# How to draw ovelrapped circles in tikz with text inside each

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-arrows

My gaol is to use draw Tikz picture of three cicles/ellipse. The three nodes should overlap. In powepoint, it is easy to make such figure. Howerver, in Tikz, I am facing some problems to show the overlap. 
[image]

```
   \documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
   \newcommand\hideit[1]{%
 \only<0| handout:1>{\mbox{}}%
 \invisible<0| handout:1>{#1}}
   \mode<presentation> {

 }
  \usetheme{CambridgeUS} 
\usepackage{comment}
   \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
 \usepackage{graphicx} 
  \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{multirow}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
 \newcommand*{\Perm}[2]{{}^{#1}\!P_{#2}}%
 \newcommand*{\Comb}[2]{{}^{#1}C_{#2}}%
\usepackage{amssymb}

    \usepackage{subfig}
   \newcommand{\mathbold}[1]{\text{\textbf{#1}}}
 \makeatletter
     \let\@@magyar@captionfix\relax
  \makeatother
    \begin{document}

  \begin{frame}{Frame Title}

  \begin{tikzpicture} 
 \node[xshift=4cm,draw,fill=green!25,ellipse,text width=5cm,align=center] 
 {
 \tiny{
 Short term
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item DO 1  DO 1  DO 1  DO 1 DO 1 DO 1 Text
  \item DO 2 Text DO 2 Text  DO 2 Text DO 2 Text
  \item DO 3  Text  DO 2 Text  DO 2 Text
  \item  DO 4 Text  DO 2 Text  DO 2 Text  DO 2 Text 

  \end{enumerate}
 }

  };

  \node[xshift=9cm,draw,fill=white!25,ellipse,text width=3cm,align=center] 
{
  \tiny{
  Short term
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item DO 1  DO 1  DO 1  DO 1 DO 1 DO 1 Text
    \item DO 2 Text DO 2 Text  DO 2 Text DO 2 Text
   \end{enumerate}
  }

   };


    \node[xshift=8cm,yshift=-3cm,draw,fill=white!25,ellipse,text width=5cm,align=center] 
 {
 \tiny{
      University
\begin{enumerate}

     \item DO 1  DO 1  DO 1  DO 1 DO 1 DO 1 Text
  \item DO 2 Text DO 2 Text  DO 2 Text DO 2 Text
     \item DO 2  DO 2  DO 2  DO 2 DO 2 DO 2 Text
 \end{enumerate}
}

 };

 \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}


  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Frame Title}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny,
    elli/.style={ellipse,text width=5cm,align=center,
        minimum height=4cm,inner xsep=-1em,inner ysep=-1em,draw}]
 \node[elli] (TL) {Short term
 \begin{itemize}
  \item DO 1  DO 1  DO 1  DO 1 DO 1 DO 1 Text
  \item DO 2 Text DO 2 Text  DO 2 Text DO 2 Text
  \item DO 3  Text  DO 2 Text  DO 2 Text
  \item  DO 4 Text  DO 2 Text  DO 2 Text  DO 2 Text 

  \end{itemize}
  };
  \node[elli,right=-0.5cm of TL] (TR) {Short term
  \begin{itemize}
    \item DO 1  DO 1  DO 1  DO 1 DO 1 DO 1 Text
    \item DO 2 Text DO 2 Text  DO 2 Text DO 2 Text
   \end{itemize}

   };
  \path (TL) -- (TR) node[elli,midway,below=0.8cm] (B) {University
    \begin{itemize}
     \item DO 1  DO 1  DO 1  DO 1 DO 1 DO 1 Text
     \item DO 2 Text DO 2 Text  DO 2 Text DO 2 Text
     \item DO 2  DO 2  DO 2  DO 2 DO 2 DO 2 Text
  \end{itemize}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or without tuning but using intersections.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric,intersections}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Frame Title}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny,
    elli/.style={ellipse,text width=5cm,align=center,
        minimum height=4cm,inner xsep=-1em,inner ysep=-1em,draw}]
 \node[elli,name path=L] (TL) {\textcolor{red}{\underline{\normalsize Short term}}
 \begin{itemize}
  \item DO 1  DO 1  DO 1  DO 1 DO 1 DO 1 Text
  \item DO 2 Text DO 2 Text  DO 2 Text DO 2 Text
  \item DO 3  Text  DO 2 Text  DO 2 Text
  \item  DO 4 Text  DO 2 Text  DO 2 Text  DO 2 Text 

  \end{itemize}
  };
  \node[elli,right=-0.5cm of TL,name path=R] (TR)
  {\textcolor{red}{\underline{\normalsize Short term}}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item DO 1  DO 1  DO 1  DO 1 DO 1 DO 1 Text
    \item DO 2 Text DO 2 Text  DO 2 Text DO 2 Text
   \end{itemize}

   };
  \path[name intersections={of=L and R}] (intersection-2) 
  node[elli,anchor=north] (B) {\textcolor{red}{\underline{\normalsize
  University}}
    \begin{itemize}
     \item DO 1  DO 1  DO 1  DO 1 DO 1 DO 1 Text
     \item DO 2 Text DO 2 Text  DO 2 Text DO 2 Text
     \item DO 2  DO 2  DO 2  DO 2 DO 2 DO 2 Text
  \end{itemize}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]